# How do the Around and AroundReplace commands work with the complexes?

Tags: complex, around

Let us consider

```
s = Around[1, 0.2] + I*Around[2, 0.3]
```

> Around[
>   Complex[1., 2.], 0.36055512754639896`]

What does it mean? The documentation to the Around command says nothing about it.

Next, the result of

```
Exp[s]
```

> Around[-1.1312 + 2.47173 I, 0.407862 - 0.891194 I

is unclear to me in view of

```
NMaximize[{ComplexExpand[Re[Exp[re + I*im]]],(re-1)^2+(im-2)^2<=0.2^2+ 0.3^2},{re,im}]
```

> {-0.184151, {re -> 0.974985, im -> 1.64031}}

Also

```
AroundReplace[Exp[re + I*im], {re -> Around[1, 0.2], im -> Around[2, 0.3]}]
```

> Around[-1.1312 + 2.47173 I, 0.552695 + 0.252945 I]

What should I trust?

Comment: A gap in the documentation was reported by me [CASE:4269367] .